# cannot use wifi

Tags: wireless, wifi-hardware-switch

After my laptop crashed I cannot use my wifi anymore. Switch on/off the wifi button on the laptop does not work. Totally stuck, suggestions are more than welcome!

Comment: Read this http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425205#425205

Comment: Please add the output of `lshw -C network` to your post.